# putting php code inside of my jquery script

Tags: php, jquery-isotope

I'm using a jQuery isotope. I found out how to reLayout after you click when it displays a textarea for a comment.

But my problem lies with jQuery when you click the comment button, it opens all of the comment boxes on the page instead of the single comment.

I was wondering if it were possible to put my COMMENT_ID in the script so that it only opens a single box instead of all of them.

my code: (that doesn't work)

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
  $('.comment '<php echo $LOGGER_ROW['COMMENT_ID'] ?>').slideDown(1000, function() {
    $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about using $(this) instead? You can get parent/children etc from this. We don't have the structure of you HTML, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: you're missing the ? in <?php

Comment: yes i realized that, i copied in the code wrong. it was there in my script, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

When rendering your HTML, if you give each comment an href attribute, then you can use jquery `attr()` function to grab that reference and only reveal that comment.

For example:

```
$('.comment').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.comment#' + id).slideDown(1000, function() {
         $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
```

I've change your code a bit so that all comments are treated as .comment class elements.

Each comment also has a unique id with it, and so the correct one slides open, of all comments available.

Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/HDBwY/

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you! this should help a lot! but how would i assign the individul id's to the separate comments in the html?

Comment: Where are you getting the comments from? Is it a database, via PHP? If so, use the database entry IDs like `<div id="<?php echo $my_db['comment_id'] ?>" class="comment"> ... ` or use php to create id's on the fly using a `for` loop for example.

Comment: i gotcha thanks! now i just have a problem with the .click function, the comment textarea it self is hidden by default obviously, so it can slide down on a click, but if theres nothing there, there is nothing to click

Comment: Ok, i tried this:

 $('.commentopen').click(function() {
  var $comment = $('comment');
  var id = $comment.attr('id');
  $('#' + id).slideDown(1000, function() {
    $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
  });
 });

still no go.

Comment: aww so close. now it opens only one, but whatever you click on it always opens the first one

Comment: you want to use `var $comment = $(this);`

Comment: `this` refers to the comment currently being clicked.

Comment: $('.commentopen').click(function() {
  var $comment = $(this);
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id).slideDown(180, function() {
    $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
  });
 }); this is what i have now, now it doeesnt open any comments :(

Comment: i see what you mean now, the problem is the thing being opened up and the thing being clicked are two totally different things

Comment: your code works perfectly if the clicked thing is doing the action. my problem is that i have a div with a link that when clicked opens a seperate box i bit down the page for comments.

Comment: Make sure you keep separate procedures, .. separate :) If you have two different click events, each requires separate coding.  They normally shouldn't affect each other. If you have another question, make a new one here, as it sounds like you're now talking about unrelated code.

Comment: not really, if you look up at the original post it shows '.commentopen' click function and then the silde down is for '.comment' that seems to be my problem, it works fine without the id stuff, but they all open up

Comment: i moved to a new answer above

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is bad. Consider this snippet:

```
$('.comment '<php echo $LOGGER_ROW['COMMENT_ID'] ?>').slideDown
```

When you substitute the PHP, it become:

```
$('.comment 'x').slideDown
```

There's an extra single quote there. Perhaps it should be a pound instead?

```
$('.comment #<php echo $LOGGER_ROW['COMMENT_ID'] ?>').slideDown
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.comment' + id).slideDown(180, function() {
         $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
```

heres what i ended up doing (which still didnt work) i gave each text area (.comment) an id, and then i gave the comment link to open the textarea(.commentopen) the exact same id, then using the this function, i obtained the same id as i use for comments. and in the html, they seem to match up row for row. but it still desnt seem to work.

Comment: Hey, apologies I made the mistake of advising two id's with the same value. You should use the href attribute for the comments button: Here is the working one: http://jsfiddle.net/HDBwY/

Comment: thank you! this works well, now i was wondering if you could get the comment div to close on a enter key, event.keyCode==13,

Comment: I"ve started you off, now you have to figure that one out. Also, would really appreciate you marking my answer for +1 or solved ... many thanks.

Comment: well to be honest im not sure how to mark it as solved, and i dont have enough reputation to +1 it :(. but yes many thanks, youve helped me a great deal.